# google cloud sdk cloudsql proxy error after deploy

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I am having issues after deploying my app.

I can connect properly via local setup using cloudsql proxy and here is the recent connection log :

```
2016/10/31 12:15:49 Listening on cloudsql/santex-1101:asia-east1:santexdb for santex-1101:asia-east1:santexdb
2016/10/31 12:15:49 Ready for new connections
2016/10/31 12:56:48 New connection for "santex-1101:asia-east1:santexdb"
```

Here is the post describing my setup and error log:

App Engine : Flexible

CloudSQL : 2nd Gen

Framework : Node.js

Node lib: mysql

I am seeing this error after I deploy :

```
2016/10/29 11:38:03 listenInstance: "santex-1101:asia-east1:santexdb"

2016/10/29 11:38:03 Remove("/cloudsql/santex-1101:asia-east1:santexdb") error: remove /cloudsql/santex-1101:asia-east1:santexdb: no such file or directory

2016/10/29 11:38:03 Open socket for "santex-1101:asia-east1:santexdb" at "/cloudsql/santex-1101:asia-east1:santexdb"

2016/10/29 11:38:03 Socket prefix: /cloudsql

2016/10/29 11:39:20 listenInstance: "santex-1101:asia-east1:santexdb"

2016/10/29 11:39:20 Remove("/cloudsql/santex-1101:asia-east1:santexdb") error: remove /cloudsql/santex-1101:asia-east1:santexdb: no such file or directory

2016/10/29 11:39:20 Open socket for "santex-1101:asia-east1:santexdb" at "/cloudsql/santex-1101:asia-east1:santexdb"

2016/10/29 11:39:20 Socket prefix: /cloudsql
```

app.js :

```
var pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 100,
    multipleStatements: true,
    user: config.get('MYSQL_USER'),
    password: config.get('MYSQL_PASSWORD'),
    database: config.get('MYSQL_DATABASE'),
    socketPath: "/cloudsql/santex-1101:asia-east1:santexdb"
});
```

app.yaml :

```
runtime: nodejs
vm: true

beta_settings:
    cloud_sql_instances: "santex-1101:asia-east1:santexdb"
```

I also did ssh into the vm to check and I can see that /cloudsql/santex-1101:asia-east1:santexdb is existing.

I am not sure what is causing this problem. I don't think it is a credentials issue either from what I can see in the messages from Logging app in the cloud console.

Thanks in advance,

timecatcher

Comment: What you're seeing in the logs isn't an error. It's simply showing you that it's opening a new socket, but first tries to remove it if it already exists, hence the 'no such file or directory'. I have a working app which shows the same log output. Are you experiencing any actual connectivity problems? You'd see something like ECONNREFUSED in the logs instead.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your error trace, it seems that the socket is created successfully toward the end. Make sure to verify if you are getting any additional error messages and check if you’re experience any observable problems with your application connecting to your Cloud SQL instance.

You can refer to Using Cloud SQL with Node.js [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/using-cloud-sql) for further information.